# How does Medicaid compare with private insurance on Healthcare.gov?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, new-jersey, medicare

How Obamacare works is that if your income is sufficiently low, then you can get Medicaid.  And if your income is too high to be eligible for Medicaid, then you'll get a Premium Tax Credit (aka the Subsidy) which you can use to buy private health insurance through Healthcare.gov.  I live in New Jersey, where if your income is between 0 and $16,643, then you're eligible for Medicaid, and thus if your income is above $16,643 you're eligible for the Premium Tax Credit.

Now I have the ability to structure my income so that it's either below $16,643 or above $16,643.  In one case, I would be eligible for Medicaid, and in the other case, I would be able to get a Silver plan on Healthcare.gov for free through the Premium Tax Credit.

So my question is, how does Medicaid compare with the private insurance plans on Healthcare.gov?  Is it as good as a Gold plan, a Silver plan, a Bronze plan, or none of the above?  Would it be harder to find doctors, hospitals, etc. that accept Medicaid compared to those who would accept a private insurance plan? I suppose that would depend on the Medicaid reimbursement rate, which varies from state to state, so again I'm from New Jersey.

EDIT: My situation has changed somewhat: I no longer have the ability to structure my income so that it's either above or below the $16,643 threshold.  Now my income is definitely going to be less than $16,643, which means I am ineligible for Obamacare subsidies.  So now my choices are either get Medicaid, or buy private insurance for full price on healthcare.org.

EDIT: This question is moot now, as I ultimately decided to get Medicaid.

Comment: The biggest thing to look out for is provider availability in the networks and prescription drug formulary.  In some states the individual exchange plan networks are roughly the same as medicare and use roughly a medicare size formulary.  There's more to this than how much the deductible is.

Comment: @quid Well. I live in New Jersey, so can you give me specific information for New Jersey?

Comment: I don't know much about NJ's specific offerings, but if you're on any maintenance drugs you should start googling them related to medicare coverage carrier plan drug formulary.  If you're young and healthy and the a silver plan is at no cost, that would probably be more broad coverage.  The issue is if the offerings in your state are stripped down to medicare then you're better off on medicaid because at least the out of pockets are lower.

Comment: @quid I am young (I'm turning 26 which is why I need to worry about this stuff), but I do take medication for diabetes.  So I should check if those drugs are in the formulary for Medicare, because Medicare will give me a rough idea of the formularies of plans on the exchange?

Comment: @quid By the way, I come from an upper middle-class family and I've been on my parents' health insurance all my life, so my biggest worry is that I'll be in for a sea change if I switch to Medicaid.  But then again I don't know much about Medicaid, I just assume it's bad because it's meant for poor people.

Comment: Medicaid would likely be a big change for you.  As far as process goes you'll likely be more comfortable just getting a plan from the exchange.  Diabetes isn't an obscure condition and a lot of relevant meds are mandated to be included.  My point is really just that the differences between group coverage, individual coverage, exchange coverage, and medicaid are more than just the copays and deductible(s).

Comment: Might want to consider whether you're going to regularly be in this income range or if you're going to be out of it (too high) very soon.  If you're going to be in the Medicaid range for a while, then might be easier to stay with it (as I wouldn't assume that subsidy is something you'll get in the future).  If you're going to be higher very soon, might want to consider non-Medicaid, some plan that's more similar to what you will likely want to have in the future, so you don't have to change doctors.

Comment: @quid I just edited my question to note the fact that I'm not going to be eligible for Obamacare subsidies.  So instead of my choice being between getting Medicaid for free vs. getting an exchange plan for free, now my choice is between getting Medicaid for free and paying full price for an exchange plan.  So what do you think the better deal would be now?  Medicaid?

Comment: To be exact: Obamacare/PPACA offered states additional money to expand Medicaid to people up to 138% FPL, but not all states chose to accept it; NJ is one that did (in spite of Christie's blustering and posturing).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, I'm aware of that; the $16,643 threshold discussed in my question is what 138% of the Federal Poverty Line works out to for me.

Comment: I think your original question is better. Having to pay full price is (probably) not going to be viable option for you. Note you could take on an additional part time job to put you back over the threshhold. I would prefer to see a comparison of the original 2 options, perhaps further breaking down the exchange plans with and without the subsidy to cover your current situation as well.

Comment: @TTT To be clear, I can afford all possible insurance plans; my individual income may be low, but my parents are the ones who are going to buy me health insurance.  So there are no options that are not "viable", it's just a matter of comparing the premiums, deductibles, networks, etc. and seeing which is the best deal.

Comment: @TTT Or by "viable" did you just mean that buying private insurance at full price is clearly worse than getting Medicaid for free?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - I should have said "not viable for most people." It's not out of the question that paying full price for an exchange plan would be preferable over Medicaid, but it seems unlikely unless you have something specific in mind that is covered only by the exchange plan. Instead, comparing just above or below the threshold certainly would be more useful information for most people, and having that information would make it easier for you to extrapolate for your specific situation of paying full price.